# "Cannot start process, the working directory ... does not exist" error in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

When I run my `Main.py` script, PyCharm keeps telling me `Cannot start process, the working directory /home/myname/PyCharmProjects/MyProjectName/mypackage does not exist`.

This error occurred after creating a package (`mypackage`) for test purposes, moving files to it (including `Main.py`), and moving the files back to the root folder afterwards.

The package `mypackage` was empty after that, but PyCharm still thought that `Main.py` is located in that package. I could still run the program until I deleted the empty package, but path errors occurred. After deleting the package, I was unable to start it.

- I can still run the other files that used to be in `mypackage` and are now in my root directory again.
- I can still create and run new files in my root directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After testing for a bit, I've found a solution (but not an answer to why this error occurs in PyCharm):

Delete the file and create it again. (Or rename or move it and create a new file with its old name, both should work.)

Comment: No need for all that! See the answer above re: `Run -> Edit Configurations`. Once there, observe that `Script path:` is wrong; click on the little folder icon and find the file. Once that's fixed, you can `run` again.

Comment: even simpler solution: click on Edit Configurations, and delete temporary configuration you were running for that file. Pycharm seems to rebuild it autmatically with correct path.

Answer (score 48):

It happens because when you create a file it automatically assigns the working directory to it's configuration, which of course is the one where you created it.

You can change that by going into `Run -> Edit Configurations`. Click on the folder icon in `Script path:` and correct the path to the file. Click `OK` to save and you should be able to `Run` the file again.

Comment: This works, but frankly I'm baffled that Pycharm doesn't handle this more gracefully. In particular, it should know to change the script path when you move the file _in Pycharm_.

Comment: Perhaps this multiple ways this can happen, but *this* is the real answer (at least for me) as opposed to deleting, renaming, commenting out things, etc. It is crazy that Pycharm seems to cache/save this and doesn't change it as expected.

Comment: I have multiple people working on a code base and I get this error because I don't have the same path to my GIT repo as someone else... if I fix the path in Config, it will break for them?

Comment: I am  really surprised  how  Pycharm  cannot  handle  that, I used  to work  with Intellij and I have never  faced this issue  before

Answer (score 5):

## Set the working directory correctly

*1. File-> Settings*

*2. Build, Execution, Deployment -> Console -> Python Console*

*3. Working directory: [The path to the directory where the file you're currently working on resides.]*

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, mine is probably related to the explaination gave by the others, it comes from the dir `.idea`, files `*.xml` contain the variable `$DIR_PROJECT$`.

Therefore, as the attribution of a new path didn't work, I just deleted my `.idea`, that is automatically loaded each time I open my project's directory.

It automatically regenerated the `.idea`, asked for the script path... And it worked perfectly

**CAREFUL** => You will automatically lose your project settings, you are deleting the "settings file"

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this same error, and the path in "edit configurations" was correct.
However, this is what eventually got my code working again.

1) I commented out all of the code in my file ("ctrl" + "a" + "ctrl" + "/")

2) I commented something I knew would compile in the file. (my list of imports)

3) I ran the python file.
This time, it actually completely compiled and after that I was able to uncomment the rest of my code and everything worked again.

Answer (score 1):

In my case `Run` -> `Edit Configuration` didn't help.
I've solved it changing the value of "WORKING_DIRECTORY" attribute in `.idea` -> `workspace.xml`

`<option name="WORKING_DIRECTORY" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/your/correct/path/here" />`

Answer (score 0):

The issue kept popping up over and over in PyCharm. So I created a new project and loaded the needed script. Then I provided the directory to path and assigned the default Python version that I wanted to use... and it worked. Then I was able to finally use "execute line in console" once again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because I renamed my project, it was "xx" I renamed it to "yy", what I did was I went through the directory of .idea in the "yy", in any of those files (all XML files) if there were the name "xx", I replaced it with "yy"

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem after moving my project to a different root directory. None of the above solutions worked for me.

I solved it by opening my entire project folder, instead of just the python file I was trying to run. And then running the file I wanted, while the entire project was loaded into PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

open the qtdesigner work dictionary setting and choose your project path then click OK, don't not use the mysterious work dictionary path by default

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner so appreciated this 6 year and 6 month discussion.  I couldn't add a comment.  I setup PyCharm 2022.1.1 and a Python 3.10.4 virtual environment with pyside2 and pyside6 on Ubuntu 22.04.  I tried all the suggestions above and could get none of them to work for me.  Following these instructions: https://pythonpyqt.com/how-to-install-pyqt5-in-pycharm/ both pyside2-designer (Qt5Designer) and pyside6-designer from my virtual environment were added as external tools.  pyside2-designer failed with the working directory error and **pyside6-designer worked without any error**.  Looking closer at pyside2-designer selecting the working directory with the browse button, I still could not create file - exit code was 127 - but the Qt5 Designer was available for existing ui files.  I used pyside2 because PyQt5-tools could not be `pip` installed in my python3.10.4 virtual env.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31781799)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on `PyCharm 2021.3.2`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My problem was caused by when I move a file from a directory which has been set as `Test sources root` to another normal directory, and then I deleted that test source directory, after doing this, that file not work any more.

`Delete the file and create it again` from @R.G work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
cd your project_dir

rm -rf .idea

restart your pycharm
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).